# Error in value[[3L]](cond) in shiny but runs locally

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to deploy an app which runs flawlessly on my local machine. But the error message within the shiny logs doesn't help me at all. Is there any way to track down so I know at least where it occurs? Then I could at least figure out why it does..

The shiny log:

```
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240280+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: ✔ dplyr   1.0.8     ✔ forcats 0.5.1
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240342+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240401+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: ✖ dplyr::filter()     masks plotly::filter(), stats::filter()
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240455+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: ✖ dplyr::group_rows() masks kableExtra::group_rows()
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240511+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: ✖ dplyr::lag()        masks stats::lag()
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240568+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggfortify':
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240620+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   method                 from    
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240939+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.ets           forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240886+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.decomposed.ts forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240673+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.Arima         forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240728+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.acf           forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240780+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.ar            forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241087+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.stl           forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.240831+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.bats          forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241241+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   fortify.ts             forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241285+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   residuals.ar           forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241009+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.forecast      forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241192+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   fitted.ar              forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241145+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   autoplot.ts            forecast
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241498+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241549+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241601+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241391+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241335+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Welcome! Want to learn more? See two factoextra-related books at https:// goo.gl/ve3WBa
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241653+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:     combine
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241445+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Attaching package: ‘gridExtra’
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241757+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Loading required package: RColorBrewer
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241822+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Loading required package: NLP
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241870+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241705+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241960+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242019+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:
2022-05-23T07:08:50.241915+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Attaching package: ‘NLP’
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242063+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242115+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:     annotate
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242163+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242215+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242267+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Attaching package: ‘stopwords’
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242314+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242357+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: The following object is masked from ‘package:tm’:
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242405+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242454+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:     stopwords
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242585+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242687+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Warning in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242749+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Warning in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242854+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242798+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Warning in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242907+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]:   invalid multibyte string at '<a0>38793<2e>49'
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242955+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
2022-05-23T07:08:50.242997+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Execution halted
2022-05-23T07:08:50.243047+00:00 shinyapps[5948139]: Shiny application exiting ...
```

The app consists of `global.R`, `ui.R` and `server.R` and consists in total of around 1300 lines.
Meanwhile, I tried to comment out quite a lot of code blocks but I didn't come any closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Motivated by the fact, that the error always occured immediately after loading the stopwords (which I wasn't aware of at the beginning at this is also the end of the code), I rearranged the package loadings slightly and since then it works.
It's weird because I didn't change anything related to this but however, it is working now. The order is now this:

```
library(tm)
library(tmap)
library(tidytext)
library(stopwords)
library(wordcloud)
```